# Android test Library gives error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the following dependencies :

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2') {
    // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since Espresso
    hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {
    // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since the test runner
    hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:rules:0.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
//ui automator test dependency
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.6.4'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'


androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.10') {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
}
androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
```

but when I import test packagesIi get test as **Cannot Resolve Symbol test error.**

> import android.support.***test***.InstrumentationRegistry;
>  import
>   android.support.***test***.espresso.ViewInteraction;
>  import
>   android.support.***test***.filters.SdkSuppress;
>  import
>   android.support.***test***.rule.ActivityTestRule;

Is there any solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your `Test.class` located?

Comment: in androidtest i have instrumentation tests

Comment: `app/src/androidTest/java`?

Comment: yes its app/src/androidTest/java

Comment: Maybe your dependencies are facing conflicts, try updating them.

Comment: Clear all of libs duplication and rebuild project

Comment: Removing duplicates does not solve the issue ... Any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

This is my dependencies for testing, try it

```
//Test
dependencies{
   androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

   androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:$testRulesVersion"
   androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:$testRulesVersion"

   androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
   core:$espressoVersion", {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
   })

   androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
   intents:$espressoVersion"

   androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
   web:$espressoVersion"
}
```

with versions

```
ext {
   testRulesVersion = '0.5'
   espressoVersion = '2.2.2'
 }
```

Comment: @NehaAgarwal Do you have any warnings while build gradle?

Comment: No there are no warnings .